# How can I use my variable from another class?

Tags: java

Im reading in a year for an album(yearReleased) and I need to subtract it from 2013. The variable yearsOld is in my Song class. Why do I keep getting errors.

TestSong.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.print(a.yearsOld);
                      ^
  symbol:   variable yearsOld
  location: variable a of type Song
1 error

```
 public class Song{

   public String title;
     public String author;
     public String interpreter;
   public int yearReleased;
     public String album;
     public String filename;

  public String getTitle(){
     return title;
}
public String getAlbum(){
     return album;
        }
public int getYearReleased(){
        return yearReleased;
}
public String getNameOfAuthor(){
        return author;

}
public String getInterpreter(){
     return interpreter;
        }
public String getFilename(){
     return filename;}

   public int yearsOld(){
    return 2013-yearReleased;}
     }
```

This is in my main

```
 public class TestSong{
public static void main(String[] args){
Song a =new Song();
a.filename="gerrr";
a.yearReleased=1988;

System.out.print(a.yearsOld);



}

}
```

Comment: The code is embarrassed that it is so poorly formatted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`yearsOld` is a method not a field. Add parenthesis to invoke it as such

```
System.out.print(a.yearsOld());
```

Aside: Use a consistent getter syntax for methods e.g.

```
public int getYearsOld()
```

This helps distinguish methods from fields.